# How to open the Sliding Navigation Drawer when ImageView is clicked?

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement the `Navigation Drawer Activity` on my Dashboard `Activity`. In my application, I have created a Theme where the 'Toolbar/ActionBar' is removed and just put an `ImageView` for my burger menu on a `custom layout` and include it on my dashboard layout. What I wanted is that when this `ImageView` is clicked the sliding drawer will display.

What I tried to do is add an `Navigation Drawer Activity` by  com.project.projectname -> New -> activity -> 'Navigation Drawer Activity' and automatically it adds `NavigationActivity class , activity_navigation.xml
app_bar_navigation.xml, etc`.

But I was wondering how can I open the drawer? 
In my `Dashboard Activity` I added this

```
 public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

   View side_tab = findViewById(R.id.side_tab);
    expanded_menu = (ImageView) side_tab.findViewById(R.id.expanded_menu);

  expanded_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // open drawer here 
        }
    });
```

Also, in `NavigationActivity` it uses `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, I must not use this because I don't apply an `ActionBar`. But what alternative can I use?

Here is my `NavigationActivity`

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Intent goToSreen;

    if (id == R.id.nav_dashboard) {
        goToSreen = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(goToSreen);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_others) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Thank you for your kind help.

---

Update

So in my Dashboard Activity I added the following

```
NavigationActivity navigationActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    View side_tab = findViewById(R.id.side_tab);
    expanded_menu = (ImageView) side_tab.findViewById(R.id.expanded_menu);

 expanded_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            navigationActivity = new NavigationActivity() ;
            navigationActivity.drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

And in my Navigation Activity I add a global variable

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

DrawerLayout drawer;


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

I have managed to call the `drawer` in my Dashboard Activity but the sliding menu still doesn't display when I clicked my burger menu. The app crashes and displays `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: create object of your navigation view and in onclick method apply 
     drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

Comment: remove default action bar from layout if you want

Comment: @AashutoshKumar should I put the drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START); on my Dashboard Activity ? I have already removed the default action bar from my layout.

Comment: @AashutoshKumar I have 2 activities right now my Dashboard Activity and NavigationActivity. Where should I edit it?

Comment: yes, first you have to create object of navigationdarwer            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extend my `NavigationActivity` to my `DashboardActivity`  like below

```
public class DashboardActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    side_tab = findViewById(R.id.side_tab);
    expanded_menu = (ImageView) side_tab.findViewById(R.id.expanded_menu);


  expanded_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            side_tab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

and then follow the said answered by @Hassan Usman and @tahsinRupam

after that I added the `DrawerLayout` in my `dashboard.xml`

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your **NavigationActivity**

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//Add this line
    public static DrawerLayout drawer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
.......
```

And next change this

```
expanded_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // open drawer here 
                NavigationActivity. drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
   });
```

Try this hope it will solve your problrm.

Comment: I'm having an error ` java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Your drawer object is null, check it properly why its null?

Comment: @mori check my answer now.

Comment: I'm not using an ActionBar and toolbar. I tried adding the `NavigationActivity. drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);` but it said that 'Cannot resolve symbol drawer'

Answer (score 1):

**Add** the following code in `NavigationActivity`:

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;    // Declare globally
```

In `onCreate()` :

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer);
 expanded_menu = (ImageView) side_tab.findViewById(R.id.expanded_menu);
expanded_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // open drawer here 
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });
```

If the drawer is open, close it `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        return;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.